# Gcov report interpretation

Tags: c++, string

I am doing code coverage on the class `cashier` and my teacher gave a very brief teaching on the meaning of the report, which I feel is very important for the development of my software engineering skills.  Hence, I would need your advice on the interpretation of the following gcov report. I would appreciate any links or articles which would help in my understanding of gcov.

**Header file**

```
#ifndef CASHIER_H
#define CASHIER_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class cashier 
{
public:

        void setID(string);
    string getID();

    void setPassword(string);
    string getPassword();

    void settries(int);
    int gettries();
        void increase_tries();

private:
    string ID;
    string Password;
    int tries;



};

#endif  /* CASHIER_H */
```

**Implementation file**

```
#include "cashier.h"




void cashier::setID(string value)
{
    this->ID = value;
}

void cashier::setPassword(string value)
{

    this->Password = value;

}

string cashier::getID()
{
    return this->ID;
}

string cashier::getPassword()
{
    return this->Password;
}

void cashier::settries(int value)
{
    this->tries=value;
}
int cashier::gettries()
{
    return this->tries;
}
void cashier::increase_tries()
{
    this->tries = this->tries + 1 ;

}
```

I type the following commands into the command prompt to use gcov on the class

```
gcov -b cashier.gnco
```

I got the following results A

```
File 'cashier.cpp'
Lines executed:100.00% of 18 //what does the 18 mean 
No branches                  //what does no branches mean
Calls executed:100.00% of 4   // what does 4 mean ??
cashier.cpp:creating 'cashier.cpp.gcov'

File '/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h' // Where did this come from ??
Lines executed:0.00% of 2
No branches
Calls executed:0.00% of 1
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h:creating 'basic_string.h.gcov
```

I type in the following command

```
gcov -f cashier.gnco
```

I got the following results B

```
Function '_ZN7cashier8settriesEi' // does this refer to the function :settries
Lines executed:100.00% of 3       // my teacher doesnt think so but i feel it refer
                                  //to it , who is correct??

Function '_ZN7cashier8gettriesEv'
Lines executed:100.00% of 2

Function '_ZN7cashier14increase_triesEv'
Lines executed:100.00% of 3

Function '_ZN7cashier11getPasswordEv'
Lines executed:100.00% of 2

Function '_ZN7cashier5getIDEv'
Lines executed:100.00% of 2

Function '_ZNSsaSERKSs'
Lines executed:0.00% of 2

Function '_ZN7cashier11setPasswordESs'
Lines executed:100.00% of 3

Function '_ZN7cashier5setIDESs'
Lines executed:100.00% of 3

File 'cashier.cpp'
Lines executed:100.00% of 18
cashier.cpp:creating 'cashier.cpp.gcov'

File '/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h'
Lines executed:0.00% of 2
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h:creating 'basic_string.h.gcov'
```

**My questions for Result A**

1. What does **18** mean and what is its significance in `Lines executed:100.00% of 18`?
2. What does `no branches` mean?
3. What does **4** mean and what is its significance in `Calls executed:100.00% of 4`?  Why are there 4 function calls when I have 7 functions in the class?
4. What does the entire paragraph mean?

   ```
   File '/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h'
       Lines executed:0.00% of 2
       No branches
       Calls executed:0.00% of 1
       /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h:creating 'basic_string.h.gcov
   ```

**My questions for Result B**

1. All the functions names etc: `_ZN7cashier8settriesEi`.  Almost matches cashier functions names etc: `void settries(int)`.  I think it refers to the same function but my teacher feels otherwise.  Which is correct?
2. What does the 3 mean in `Lines executed:100.00% of 3`for the function `_ZN7cashier8settriesEi`?

Answer (score 1):

Read the man page. Type `man gcov` in a terminal window. Also, google gcov. There are instructions on the web.

- gcov -b looks for branches. Your code has no branches (no if statements, no loops), so using the -b option is a bit meaningless here.
- gcov -f gives a summary for each function. It omits the branch probabilities.

With regard to the numbers, sometimes gcov counts open and close braces as executable statements, sometimes it doesn't. It's a bit of a pain in the rear. Look at the cashier.cpp.gcov file to see which lines counted, which lines didn't.

Regarding names such as _ZN7cashier8settriesEi: That's the mangled name for `cashier::settries(int)`. Pass those names through c++filt.

Regarding /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h, ignore those files. They aren't yours, but they're going to appear in the gcov output.

Comment: Great tip about c++filt!